# MySQL Workbench Alter Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

i have a problem with my workbench program. I use Mac Lion OS X and mysql workbench program. When i want to do any procedure to alter that doesn't work. Which is show to the procedure code i right click it, after "Alter Procedure" click but doesn't happen anything!

i'm updated to MySQL Workbench program "5.2.45 revision 10251" to  "5.2.47  revision 10398" but both are can not make alter procedure. And one odd thing is alter table is working fine.

Have u got any idea why doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the [ALTER ROUTINE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-procedure.html) privilege? See if you can create an own procedure and alter that.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution how I fixed this:

1) Add "mysql" database to the user, you are logged in with

Advice: now you can alter functions and procedures

2) Add the global privilege "SUPER" to your user

Advice: otherwise you will get the following error if you save the procedure/function: "ERROR 1227: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation"